# How can I open a PDF file using Intent in Android Nougat?

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent, android-developer-api

I appreciate your help so that my code can open a PDF file with an Intent, this is the code i have been using:

```
String pathFile =
    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() +
    FileUtils.PATH_SEPARATOR + "myFolder" +
    FileUtils.PATH_SEPARATOR + "myFile.pdf";
File pdfFile = new File( pathFile );
if ( pdfFile.exists() ) {
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile( new File( pathFile ) );
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
    intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
    intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

But I understand that now (from the Android-N version) the privileges are handled differently and so i hope you can help me by indicating what changes i have to make to get a PDF file opened using an Intent.

PS: In my AndroidManifest.xml I am looking for all permissions in the STORAGE:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Have you given permission for read external storage?

Comment: I have the permission request on my AndroidManifest.xml about STORAGE

Comment: Have you declared run time permissions, because from nogout onward we need declare run time permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was found at: http://android.2317887.n4.nabble.com/FileProvider-td394588.html

Terrific!.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
try {
    String newFilePath = filePath.replaceAll("%20", " ");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(newFilePath), "application/pdf");
    } else {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(newFilePath);
        File file = new File(uri.getPath());
        if (file.exists()){
            uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
   startActivity(intent);
```